# How to integrate with Google home hub to get camera stream?

Tags: camera, google-smart-home

For now, the media target is just Chromecast service  from document here:https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/camerastream.html#response-nodejs

but,You can stream video from these security cameras to your Google Home Hub from document here:
https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9137164?hl=en-AU&ref_topic=7029100

so,how to integrate with Google home hub to get camera stream?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the guide on [CameraStream](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/camerastream.html), it will show you how to integrate with any cast target. The Google Home Hub is a cast target, and a security camera will stream to it if the Hub is the target receiver.

Comment: OK,We have realized showing camera video on TV through chromecast. we will test the home hub next, thank you!

Comment: Hi nick,Can I integrate the Google Assistant voice service into our camera? We want to develop a camera with voice

Comment: That's an entirely different question.